# EVE Online starter pack on Steam: can I start later?

Tags: steam, eve-online

I don't really have time to play EVE right now, but in a few weeks I presume I will.

If I purchase a EUR5 starter pack currently on Steam sale, will the 30 days of game time start ticking down *only after* I activate the account, or will it start ticking down immediately?

Comment: Try to get in touch with someone from the eve community. They are able to get you a 30 day free trial (at least i was able when i played eve). Benefits for them are free game time if you continue to play after the trial period.

Comment: The trial is 21 days with a referral link, 14 days without it, at the moment. It's been that way at least since i started playing 5 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last comments on forum in [this topic](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1684072&page=2) said that your time will start after purchasing starter pack. Quote:

> Oh and by the way your 30 days start from the time you purchased the
>   game in to your Steam account

Comment: Can you apply the starter pack to an existing account?

Comment: I don't know how it works now, but in the past it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Starts right away with the purchase. And one funny "bug" - if you buy 3-month subscription, then cancel it (no matter the reason) you'll need to wait until those 3 months end to buy another one. So - be ware.
Also you won't be able to use old Eve account (non-steam) if you have

Comment: Then do NOT get the steam version ever. Since it is very plausible to have two clients open at the same time. Most people i knew, including myself, had multiple accounts.